# npm install --production ignore my dependencies

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I have this `package.json`:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "browser-sync": "^2.26.14",
        "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.19",
        "less": "^3.13.1",
        "less-loader": "^7.3.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```

Just for testing how do work NodeJS, NPM, Laravel and Laravel Mix (Webpack) together, I run:

`npm install --production` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install)

> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.

## Actual behavior

When I go to `node_modules` folder, I don't see any `cross-env` package there. Moreover the output of the command line is:

`$ npm install --production`

> up to date, audited 1 package in 17s

> found 0 vulnerabilities

, meaning no package (in particular: `cross-env`) was installed.

## Expected behavior

`cross-env` (and only `cross-env`) would be installed, being part of `dependencies`, with this command: `npm run install --production`.

## Question

Why does `dependencies` array seem to be ignored by NPM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `cross-env` also listed in `devDependencies`. Dependencies should only be declared in one location. Perhaps npm ignored `cross-env` as it is listed in `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this occurs even if the dependency is not explicitly listed twice in `package.json` but is a sub-dependency of a package declared in `dependencies`. My example:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sharp": "^0.26.1" // depends on "color" which depends on "color-convert"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "color-convert": "^2.0.1" 
  }
}
```

In this example, `color-convert` will NOT be installed if running `npm install --only=production` even though it is a dependency of a production dependency (using npm v6.14.14)

Comment: So what is the solution to this?

Comment: I tried to recreate this issue and could not, all of the `sharp` dependencies are always installed. I ran `rm -fr node_modules` before each test and got the same result when running `npm i`, `npm ci`, `npm i --only=production`, `npm i --production`, and `npm i --omit=dev`. I tested with Node versions 8, 10, 12, 14, and 16. This no longer appears to be an issue.